# Why GuID is not generated when new record is Inserted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am trying to insert new record into my database.

everything works except when a new record is added , the database user id which is a Guid not generated, however if I enter a new record into the database directly the new Guid is generated

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new User Object
    User newUser = new User();

    newUser.user_name = txtRegisterUserName.Text;
    newUser.password = txtRegisterPassword.Text;

    // Add the new object to the Users collection.
    userDB.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);

    // Submit the change to the database.
    userDB.SubmitChanges();
        txtRegisterUserName.Text = "";
        txtRegisterPassword.Text = "";
        lblMessage.Text = "Record has been added";
}
```

Here is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] 
(
    [user_id]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [password]  VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([user_id] ASC)
);
```

The first attempt works and a new user is added but with Guid like this (000-00000-000000) and when I try to add a new record, the database generates nothing but the same (000-00000-000000) and this is the error I get

> Additional information: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__User__B9BE370FC96CCDEF'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing any details it looks like `user_id` is defined and created as `000-00000-000000` in your `User` instance.

Comment: but when i try to generate a new Guid and insert that into database , still 000-00000-000000 inserted .for instance if i say something like newUser.user_id = new Guid(); i still get the same 000-00000-000000 as my id in my database

Comment: `new Guid()` is the same as empty Guid. You want to do `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate a new unique `Guid`.

Comment: just tried that and got the same error.. what is the point of newid() as default in my database then ???

Comment: open you EDMX diagram, select the user_id property  and open the properties window.  Ensure that StoreGeneratedPattern is set to identity.

Comment: To use the default value DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL your insert command should be "Insert Into [dbo].[User]([user_name], [password]). Do not specify [user_id]

Answer (score 1):

What i ended up to do is to generate a new GuID before instantiating my new user and then set that as my user_id ... not sure if it s a right way but it s working for now

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Generating new GuID 
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    // Create a new User Object
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.user_id = guid;
    newUser.user_name = txtRegisterUserName.Text;
    newUser.password = txtRegisterPassword.Text;


    // Add the new object to the Users collection.
    userDB.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);

    // Submit the change to the database.
    userDB.SubmitChanges();
        txtRegisterUserName.Text = "";
        txtRegisterPassword.Text = "";
        lblMessage.Text = "Record has been added";

}
```